# Find all solutions for $B$ of $AB=H$ where $A,H$ are rectangular matrices of a given rank

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-rank

Let the size of the a matrix $A$ be $n\times m$ and  $n\times p$ of a matrix $H$ and assume $\mathrm{rank(A)}=\mathrm{rank(H)}=n$ and $m>p>n$. How do I find all possible solutions for $B$ (whose size is $m\times p$) in the matrix equation
$$
AB=H
$$ 
?

The obvious choice is to calculate 
$$
B=A^{-1}H
$$
where the pseudoinverse (say it exists and is unique) was used. Because $\mathrm{rank(A^{-1})}=n$, this gives a solution for $B$ whose rank is at most $n$. But the rank of $B$ can be as high as $p$. How do I get all the remaining (higher-rank) solutions for $B$?

Also, once I get a solution for rank $q>n$, is it the unique solution $B$ of rank $q$?

Comment: why downvoted ?

Comment: Why downvoted again? Can the anonymous face have enough courage to tell me what is wrong with my question? I'll be happy to correct it...

Comment: Don't worry about it.  There seem to be at least two users on downvoting sprees at the moment.  The question seems fine to me at a glance.

Comment: @TrevorWilson  Hmm so math-SE has become a lawless country since my last visit some time ago...?

Comment: I guess I'm even more out of the loop than you are, because I missed when it became a country :-)

Comment: @TrevorWilson   :) but fun aside, doesn't it affect whether my question gets noticed? I have 5 views (me+you+2 serial downvoters) so this makes it one other view only. Oh boy

Comment: Other users than the downvoter themself can only speculate what was the reason for the downvote. But if you wish to discuss the reason for the downvote, there is a chatroom [explicitly for this purpose](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21818649#21818649).

Comment: Although, as Trevor said, this case might be related to [this incident](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20661/nearly-all-frontpage-questions-downvoted).

Answer (score 1):

If $m<n$ and $A$ has full rank, then $A^TA$ is invertible. So there is a unique solution
$$
B=(A^TA)^{-1}A^TH
$$

In your case $m>n$, consider the following equation:
$AXB=C$

Its general solution is $(A\otimes B^T)\overline{X}=\overline{C}$, where $\otimes$ is Kronecker Symbol, $\overline{X}$ is formed by putting rows of $X$ in a single vector, so is $\overline{C}$.

In your case, consider

$(A\otimes I)\overline{B}=\overline{H}$

Where $\overline{B}$ is formed by putting rows of $B$ in a single vector, so is $\overline{H}$.

If $\operatorname{rank}(A\otimes I,\overline{H})= \operatorname{rank}(A\otimes I)$, then there is a unique solution.

Comment: How is $\mathrm{rank}(A\otimes I,\bar{H})$ defined ? What does the commna mean?

Comment: I think you got it wrong. The vectorization $\bar{C}$ is a transposed flattened matrix $C$, not the formed by putting columns of $C$ in a column vector (it would have to be $(B^T\otimes A)$ I think).